# Magento 1.6.2 event observer doesnt work

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to implement observer in my module (app/code/community/Test/Shipping).

My files are: **app/code/community/Test/Shipping/etc/config.xml** global part only

```
<global>
    <models>
        <test_shipping>
            <class>Test_Shipping_Model</class>
        </test_shipping>
    </models>
    <events>
        <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
            <observers>
                <Test_Shipping_Observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>test_shipping/observer</class>
                    <method>checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after</method>
                </Test_Shipping_Observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

**app/code/community/Test/Shipping/Model/Observer.php** i replaced some values in curl but its tested and works with correct values.

```
<?php
```

class Test_Shipping_Model_Observer {

```
public function checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $requests = array(
        "username" => "test",
        "password" => "test",
        "environment" => "development",
        "action" => "ship",
        "service_id" => "1"
    );
    $url = "";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($requests));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

}

**app/etc/modules/Test_Shipping.xml** with starting and ending config tags to, couldnt get them in my code example.

```
<modules>
    <Test_Shipping>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>community</codePool>
    </Test_Shipping>
</modules>
```

But observer doens't work, can anyone help me please? Is there a way to check if method is called so i would know that observer works but my curl doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the `<config>/<modules>` part of your config.xml ?

Anyways, apart from the function name of your observer that is non-magento friendly, it should work (you should call like `executeCurlAfterOrderSave()`)

To be sure it is called :

- Activate the Log functionnality in Backoffice (Menu System / Configuration / Developer / Log Settings
- add a `Mage::log('event just dispatched');` just after the

  Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after',
                      array('order'=>$order, 'quote'=>$this->getQuote()));

that is called in the `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage` (or `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Api` is you're using the API)
note: revert this change that's only for debugging purpose as you must not modify core files.

- add a `Mage::log('even should be captured here');` in the beginning of your Observer method
- test your code and look at the var/log folder to see if what happened (what has been logged)

Good luck

Comment: <config>
    <modules>
        <Test_Shipping>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </Test_Shipping>
    </modules>

Comment: Mage::log('event just dispatched'); was in logs but Mage::log('even should be captured here'); didnt, so that means my observer doesnt work

Comment: Yep. Try renaming <Test_Shipping_Observer> in <test_shipping> and rename the observer function as I suggested.

Comment: observer workks now i guess...but is it normal that Mage::log('even should be captured here'); gets loged before Mage::log('event just dispatched'); ?

Comment: Yep it's normal because the displatchEvent method call your observer (and your log) and is before the line Mage::log('event just dispatched');

Answer (score -1):

Your config.xml is wrong,

```
<global>
<models>
    <test_shipping>
        <class>Test_Shipping_Model</class>
    </test_shipping>
</models>   
</global>

 <events>
    <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
        <observers>
            <Test_Shipping_Observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>test_shipping/observer</class>
                <method>checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after</method>
            </Test_Shipping_Observer>
        </observers>
    </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
</events>
```

Comment: puting <events> outside <global> didnt help

Comment: had to use <frontend> and </frontend>, now i can see in log that observer is called....thx alot